# Wanting: Handbook of Mathematical Equations

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

About 40 years ago, I had a "Handbook of Mathematical Equations". It was hardcover with an orange dust jacket. I seem to have lost it and I may not even be remembering the exact name. Does anybody recognize the book by my description and know if it is available, in-print or out-of-print?

Alternatively, can someone recommend a comprehensive handbook of math?

Comment: "A comprehensive handbook of math" is rather subjective as you're very unlikely to find $1+1=2$ (in the trivial sense) and $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^s}}$ in the same book.

Comment: You'd be better off buying handbooks for different fields of math separately

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://www.amazon.com/Standard-Mathematical-Formulas-Advances-Mathematics/dp/1498777805/) is what you are looking for.

Comment: This one was first published in the 70s: https://www.amazon.com/Handbook-Mathematical-Formulas-Richard-Burington/dp/0070090157/ref=la_B001HD237C_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1529078837&sr=1-1

Comment: The book I had showed integrals, derivatives, standard deviation, and a [figurative] hundred  other things.

Comment: [This](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/academic/subjects/mathematics/abstract-analysis/nist-handbook-mathematical-functions?format=WW&isbn=9780521140638) one might be good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably thinking of Handbook of Mathematical Functions, Milton Abramowitz and Irene A. Stegun, Eds., National Bureau of Standards Applied Mathematics Series, Vol. 55, published by the U.S. Department of Commerce, 1964, 1046pp.    This hardback edition has an orange cover.

There's also a Dover edition that was printed in paperback.

You can find the whole volume online at   http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Handbook-Mathematical-Functions-Formulas-Graphs/dp/B005J875CO/ref=sr_1_9?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1529089461&sr=1-9&keywords=Handbook+of+Mathematical+Functions%2C+Milton+Abramowitz

Comment: Thanks to user15994 and Phil H for finding the book and I prefer hardcover so thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

how about this one from the 1960s: [https://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Handbook-Scientists-Engineers-Definitions/dp/0486411478](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486411478)

Comment: I'm sure it's a good book but I did find the one I was wanting. I've got your suggestion on my wishlist for things I may want to explore later.